# Check in DeleteView if its post or get? django

Tags: django

Im trying to check either a user tried to enter a url by himself or he follows the urls and put the values needed in the form i build for him..
In some Ungeneric class, I can check that thing -

```
if request.method == 'GET':
```

But in DeleteView i can't do that thing so i don't know how to prevent from the user from doing bad things by input url by himself.
How can i use a function that does the same in generic View and checks if the user enter a url by himself or fill in the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `DeleteView` does deletion only on `POST` request. So your user will not be able to delete items just making `GET` request.

But for your information all class based views(CBV) call `dispatch` method which then calls ether `post` or `get` depending on `request.method`.

You can add some logic directly in `dispatch` method or modify `get` and do your checks there

**Example**

```
class MyDeleteView(DeleteView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # here you can make redirect to any url
        ...
```

Comment: This is just the problem! its sends me to 404 page. i dont want it! i want it to deliver me to the index by checking if the request was Get

Answer (score 1):

It should be a POST, there isn't any need to check it yourself.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview)

> The given object will only be deleted if the request method is POST. If this view is fetched via GET, it will display a confirmation page that should contain a form that POSTs to the same URL.